# want to pass id from mongodb database collection in react table and react form using button

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-table-v7, react-forms

I am doing a project in which I need to show all the product information from the MongoDB database in UI. This data will be shown in UI in tabular form. So I want to use react table. In each row, there will be a button to delete that product information from the UI and also from MongoDB. I am trying to pass the id to button but every time I am getting undefined. value. How can I pass MongoDB product id correctly to react table?

though I am doing it in the following way. But I really want to do it in react table.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import auth from '../../firebase.init';
import './Table.css'


const Table = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth)
    const email = user.email

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://polar-castle-01342.herokuapp.com/inventory`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setData(data))
}, [])


const handleDeleteButton = async id => {
    const proceed = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product?')
    if (proceed) {
        const url = `https://polar-castle-01342.herokuapp.com/inventory/${id}`
        const response = await axios.delete(url)
        const remaining = data.filter(item => item._id !== id)
        setData(remaining)
    }
}

return (
    <div className='mt-5 table-responsive'>
        <h1 className='text-center mb-3'>Inventory Products</h1>
        <table border={1} cellPadding={5} className='w-100'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Supplier Name</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {data.map(product => (
                    <tr key={product._id}>
                        <td>{product._id}</td>
                        <td>{product.name}</td>
                        <td>{product.price}</td>
                        <td>{product.quantity}</td>
                        <td>{product.supplierName}</td>
                        <td><button onClick={() => handleDeleteButton(product._id)} className='delete-button'>Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
);

};



export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this
`const handleDeleteButton = async id => {

```
const proceed = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product?')
if (proceed) {
    const url = `https://polar-castle-01342.herokuapp.com/inventory/${id}`
    const response = await axios.delete(url)
    const remaining = data.filter(item => item._id !== id)
    setData(remaining)
}
```

}`and` useEffect(() => {
fetch(`https://polar-castle-01342.herokuapp.com/inventory`)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => setData(data))
}, [handleDeleteButton])`
I hope it'll useful